# SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, laravel-6

When trying to upload an image to the laravel storage im getting an error.

> SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for C:\xampp\tmp\php3624.tmp

But im not even using the SplFileInfo function.
Here is my code.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required|max:191',
            'sub_title' => 'required|max:191',
            'description' => 'required',
            'active' => 'required',
            'img' => 'image|mimes:jpg,png,svg,gif,jpeg|max:2048'
        ]);

        $services = new Services;
        if($request->hasFile('img')){
            $imageName = time().'_NEWS.'.$request->file('img')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // dd($request->file('img')->getMaxFilesize());
            $services->news_image = $imageName;
            $request->file('img')->move(public_path('storage/services/'), $imageName);


        }
        $services->title = $request->input('title');
        $services->sub_title = $request->input('sub_title');
        $services->description = $request->input('description');
        $services->active = $request->input('ative');
        $services->save();

        return redirect('/admin/services')->with('success', 'Succesvol een behandeling aangemaakt');
    }
```

I hope somebody can help me out here. i already know its a Symfony bug but i cant find any answers to my problem. I have already changed my

> post_max_size=40M and upload_max_filesize=40M

in PHP.ini so that wont be the issue.

Comment: in which line of your code is the error/exception triggered?

Comment: You are using SplFileInfo indirectly. Laravel uses Symfony's HttpFoundation-component and when you use `$request->file('img')` you will get back an [UploadedFile](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php#L32), which extends File which then in turn extends \SplFileInfo. The error message hints at some issue with the uploaded file's size. Have you checked whether the ini values are overwritten somewhere? Maybe use `ini_get('upload_max_filesize')` in your controller to make sure

Comment: @dbrumann, i used the command `dd(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));` it gave me back 40M to it didn't overwrite it self.

Comment: @Jakumi, the error is triggerd on `$imageName = time().'_NEWS.'.$request->file('img')->getClientOriginalExtension();` so the first line inside of the curly brackets.

Comment: so essentially, the file that is supposed to exist, doesn't exist (anymore) or isn't accessible (-> stat fails). There is a long standing problem with php that requires to set enctype on the form element (please check if your form has that): https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php (the max_file_size one is - as far as I know - optional, but you could add it just to be safe). otherwise: is it possible that laravel (re)moves the file on its own somehow?

Comment: @Jakumi, We already had `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in our form. Do you maybe know another way to upload images in laravel?

Comment: I do not. I'm coming from the symfony tag and I'm actually not familiar with laravel. I hope, laravel has some form of profiler/debug mode to check if the POST request actually contains the file... ?

Comment: @Jakumi, Oh okay. The POST request contains the file.

Comment: just for kicks and giggles, can you `var_dump($request->file('img')->isReadable())`  before and after the `$this->validate` call? maybe it's already gone at the start, but maybe at some point it disappears.

Comment: @Jakumi they both return `bool(true)`.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#file-uploads have you checked this? it uses this stuff slightly differently. also, if `isReadable` returns true, the file should exist and stat should work. can you also check `getSize` on the file. maybe it's really just `stat` but that would be just wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error occured because you have move()d the file and then getSize()d the object. Try to set a variable and assign the size and then move the file.

```
{
     ...
     $size=$request->file('img')->getSize();
     $request->file('img')->move(public_path('storage/services/'), $imageName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me get around the problem.
Maybe not the best solution but it worked for me.

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|max:191',
        'sub_title' => 'required|max:191',
        'description' => 'required',
        'active' => 'required',
        'img' => 'image|mimes:jpg,png,svg,gif,jpeg|max:2048'
    ]);

    $services = new Services;
    if($request->hasFile('img')){
        $imageName = time().'_NEWS.'.$request->file('img')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        // dd($request->file('img')->getMaxFilesize());
        $services->news_image = $imageName;
        $request->file('img')->move(public_path('storage/services/'), $imageName);
        $size=$request->file('img')->getSize();   


    }
    $services->title = $request->input('title');
    $services->sub_title = $request->input('sub_title');
    $services->description = $request->input('description');
    $services->active = $request->input('ative');
    $services->save();

    return redirect('/admin/services')->with('success', 'Succesvol een behandeling aangemaakt')->with($size);
}
```